# How To Create A Table in Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, tabstop

I've posted this before, but I'm reposting it with more detailed information.

This is my assignment:
[image]

[image]

And, so far, this is my code:

```
# Define a function that caculates average test scores
def calculate_average(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5):
    total = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5
    average = total % 5
    print(average)

# Define a function that determines a letter grade
# Based on the given score
def determine_grade(score):
    if score < 60:
        print 'F'
    elif score => 60 or score <= 69:
        print 'D'
    elif score => 70 or score <= 79:
        print 'C'
    elif score => 80 or score <= 89:
        print 'B'
    elif score => 90 or score <= 100:
        print 'A'
# Define a function that prompts the user to input names and test scores
def input_data():
    score1 = input('Enter score 1:')
    name1 = input('Enter name 1:')
    score2 = input('Enter score 2:')
    name2 = input('Enter name 2:')
    score3 = input('Enter score 3:')
    name3 = input('Enter name 3:')
    score4 = input('Enter score 4:')
    name4 = input('Enter name 4:')
    score5 = input('Enter score 5:')
    name5 = input('Enter name 5:')


# Define a function that displays a letter grade for each score
# followed by the student's name and the average test score
def display_menu():
```

As I said in the first post, I don't have a real problem with anything except setting up that table. I'm really confused!

I asked my instructor (this is an online course, BTW), and he said: "Its just using the print operator, like you have done in previous modules, your printing text , variables and the return value of a function."

Now I'm just wondering where to start.

**EDIT:** I've updated my code this:

```
# Define a function that prompts the user to input names and test scores
def input_data():
    score1 = input('Enter score 1:')
    name1 = input('Enter name 1:')
    score2 = input('Enter score 2:')
    name2 = input('Enter name 2:')
    score3 = input('Enter score 3:')
    name3 = input('Enter name 3:')
    score4 = input('Enter score 4:')
    name4 = input('Enter name 4:')
    score5 = input('Enter score 5:')
    name5 = input('Enter name 5:')

# Define a function that determines a letter grade
# Based on the given score
def determine_grade(score):
    if score < 60:
        print ('F')
    elif 60 <= score <= 69:
        print ('D')
    elif  70 <= score <= 79:
        print ('C')
    elif 80 <= score <= 89:
        print ('B')
    elif 90 <= score <= 100:
        print ('A')

# Define a function that caculates average test scores
def calculate_average(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5):
    total = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5
    average = total / 5
    print(average)

# Define a function that displays a letter grade for each score
# followed by the student's name and the average test score
def display_menu():
    for x in range(10):
        print("{:<10}".format("{:0.1f}".format(x)), end='')
    print ("Name\t\t\tnumeric grade\t\tletter grade")
print ("---------------------------------------------------------------")
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s") % ('name1', 'score1', determine_grade)
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s") % ('name2', 'score2', determine_grade)
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s") % ('name3', 'score3', determine_grade)
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s") % ('name4', 'score4', determine_grade)
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s") % ('name5', 'score5', determine_grade)
print ("---------------------------------------------------------------")
```

But when I run it:
[image]

**EDIT #2:** This is my code currently:

```
# Define a function that prompts the user to input names and test scores
def input_data():
    score1 = input('Enter score 1:')
    name1 = input('Enter name 1:')
    score2 = input('Enter score 2:')
    name2 = input('Enter name 2:')
    score3 = input('Enter score 3:')
    name3 = input('Enter name 3:')
    score4 = input('Enter score 4:')
    name4 = input('Enter name 4:')
    score5 = input('Enter score 5:')
    name5 = input('Enter name 5:')

# Define a function that caculates average test scores
def calculate_average(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5):
    total = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5
    average = total / 5
    print(average)

# Define a function that determines a letter grade
# Based on the given score
def determine_grade(score):
    if score < 60:
        print ('F')
    elif 60 <= score <= 69:
        print ('D')
    elif  70 <= score <= 79:
        print ('C')
    elif 80 <= score <= 89:
        print ('B')
    elif 90 <= score <= 100:
        print ('A')



# Define a function that displays a letter grade for each score
# followed by the student's name and the average test score
def display_menu():
   print ("Name\t\t\tnumeric grade\t\tlettergrade")
print ("---------------------------------------------------------------")
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name1', 93, 'A'))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name2', 89, 'B'))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name3', 76, 'C'))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name4', 58, 'F'))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name5', 98, 'A'))
print ("---------------------------------------------------------------")
print (calculate_average)
```

And this is what happens when I run it:

[image]

Now, I have mainly two problems:

1) How do I get the input statements to execute and enter the data BEFORE the table is displayed?

2) How do I convert the numbers displayed so that they are in the '.2f' format? (I've already tried a few ways and none of them worked).

**HOPEFULLY THE FINAL EDIT:** I'm getting really close to the solution, but need help with a few more things.

Here is my code:

```
# Define a function that prompts the user to input names and test scores

score = input('Enter score 1:')
name1 = input('Enter name 1:')
score = input('Enter score 2:')
name2 = input('Enter name 2:')
score = input('Enter score 3:')
name3 = input('Enter name 3:')
score = input('Enter score 4:')
name4 = input('Enter name 4:')
score = input('Enter score 5:')
name5 = input('Enter name 5:')




# Define a function that determines a letter grade
# Based on the given score
def determine_grade(score):
    if score < 60:
        print ('F')
    elif 60 <= score <= 69:
        print ('D')
    elif  70 <= score <= 79:
        print ('C')
    elif 80 <= score <= 89:
        print ('B')
    elif 90 <= score <= 100:
        print ('A')

determine_grade(score)


# Define a function that caculates average test scores
def calculate_average(score):
    total = score + score + score + score + score
    average = total / 5
    print(average)

calculate_average(score)

# Define a function that displays a letter grade for each score
# followed by the student's name and the average test score
def display_menu():
   print ("Name\t\t\tnumeric grade\t\tlettergrade")
print ("---------------------------------------------------------------")
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name1', 'score', determine_grade('score')))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name2', 'score', determine_grade('score')))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name3', 'score', determine_grade('score')))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name4', 'score', determine_grade('score')))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name5', 'score', determine_grade('score')))
print ("---------------------------------------------------------------")
calculate_average(score)
```

And this is what happens when I press F5:

[image]

**GUYS, I'M ALMOST DONE JUST NEED HELP WITH FORMATTING:** 
I created another file so I could reorganize my code a bit, so that's why there's no comments. This is what I have:

```
score1 = float(input('Enter score 1:'))
name1 = input('Enter name 1:')
score2 = float(input('Enter score 2:'))
name2 = input('Enter name 2:')
score3 = float(input('Enter score 3:'))
name3 = input('Enter name 3:')
score4 = float(input('Enter score 4:'))
name4 = input('Enter name 4:')
score5 = float(input('Enter score 5:'))
name5 = input('Enter name 5:')


def determine_letter_grade1(score1):
    if score1 < 60.0:
        print ('F')
    elif 60.0 <= score1 <= 69.0:
        print ('D')
    elif  70.0 <= score1 <= 79.0:
        print ('C')
    elif 80.0 <= score1 <= 89.0:
        print ('B')
    elif 90.0 <= score1 <= 100.0:
        print ('A')

def determine_letter_grade2(score2):
    if score2 < 60.0:
        print ('F')
    elif 60.0 <= score2 <= 69.0:
        print ('D')
    elif  70.0 <= score2 <= 79.0:
        print ('C')
    elif 80.0 <= score2 <= 89.0:
        print ('B')
    elif 90.0 <= score2 <= 100.0:
        print ('A')

def determine_letter_grade3(score3):
    if score3 < 60.0:
        print ('F')
    elif 60.0 <= score3 <= 69.0:
        print ('D')
    elif  70.0 <= score3 <= 79.0:
        print ('C')
    elif 80.0 <= score3 <= 89.0:
        print ('B')
    elif 90.0 <= score3 <= 100.0:
        print ('A')

def determine_letter_grade4(score4):
    if score4 < 60.0:
        print ('F')
    elif 60.0 <= score4 <= 69.0:
        print ('D')
    elif  70.0 <= score4 <= 79.0:
        print ('C')
    elif 80.0 <= score4 <= 89.0:
        print ('B')
    elif 90.0 <= score4 <= 100.0:
        print ('A')

def determine_letter_grade5(score5):
    if score5 < 60.0:
        print ('F')
    elif 60.0 <= score5 <= 69.0:
        print ('D')
    elif  70.0 <= score5 <= 79.0:
        print ('C')
    elif 80.0 <= score5 <= 89.0:
        print ('B')
    elif 90.0 <= score5 <= 100.0:
        print ('A')

average = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5) / 5.0

def determine_letter_grade_avg(average):
    if average < 60.0:
        print ('F')
    elif 60.0 <= average <= 69.0:
        print ('D')
    elif  70.0 <= average <= 79.0:
        print ('C')
    elif 80.0 <= average <= 89.0:
        print ('B')
    elif 90.0 <= average <= 100.0:
        print ('A')

def display_menu():
    for x in range(10):
        print("{:<10}".format("{:0.1f}".format(x)), end='')
    print ("Name\t\t\tnumeric grade\t\tletter grade")
print ("---------------------------------------------------------------")
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % (name1, score1, determine_letter_grade1(score1)))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % (name2, score2, determine_letter_grade2(score2)))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % (name3, score3, determine_letter_grade3(score3)))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % (name4, score4, determine_letter_grade4(score4)))
print ("%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % (name5, score5, determine_letter_grade5(score5)))
print ("---------------------------------------------------------------")
print ('Average Score:', average, determine_letter_grade_avg(average))
```

And when I run it:

[image]

Comment: I think you should start with correcting `determine_grade`: use `>=` instead of `=>` and use `and` instead of `or`.

Comment: Use the idea of tabstops—https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop

Comment: The example Arun Das gave was in Python 2 syntax. To fix it, move the first closing bracket `)` to the end of the line, after the 2nd closing bracket

Comment: Made the fix, Steven Summers, but now it says "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: Hey everybody, I'm almost finished but need help with a couple of things. See the stuff under **Hopefully my final edit:**

Comment: Check the updates under **GUYS, I'M ALMOST DONE JUST NEED HELP WITH FORMATTING:**

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking towards `str.format()` and `end=''` for your print statement

Here's a little example

```
for x in range(10):
    print("{:<10}".format("{:0.1f}".format(x)), end='')
```

The first part for the rounding to 1 decimal place for your float values is

```
"{:0.1f}".format(x)
```

The `0` is for no left padding, the following `.1f` is for rounding to 1 decimal place. Next is the main part

```
"{:<10}".format(...)
```

This will print with a minimum string length of 10 characters. So if you have a string such as `Hello` it is printed as `Hello_____` ( _ to represent empty spaces) The `10` can be changed to a value of your choosing.

Finally the `end=''`. By default the `end` parameter is `\n` which is what creates the new line after each print, but by changing it you can form lines from multiple print statements. Just print normally or set `end='\n'` when you want to end the line.

Little something to note as well. When checking if a value is between two integers you can use this instead of checking it twice (also you would need and `and` operator instead of `or` )

```
elif 60 <= score <= 69:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def display_menu():
print "Name\t\t\tnumeric grade\t\tlettergrade"
print "---------------------------------------------------------------"
print "%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name1', 50, 'F')
print "%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name2', 50, 'F')
print "%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name3', 23, 'F')
print "%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name4', 44, 'F')
print "%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s" % ('name5', 48, 'F')
print "---------------------------------------------------------------"
```

display_menu()

I used `\t` to give tabs in between.

[This is the screenshot of the PythonShell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pINM6.png)

Comment: It said "invalid syntax" after the "%s:\t\t\t%f\t\t%s", and indicated the quotation mark at the end. I'm using Python 3.4.3., if that helps.

Comment: Sorry I am using v2.7. That is why it didn't work for you. Let me just run a quick check.

Comment: It's alright, Arun. I figured out the syntax. I'm almost on my way to a solution, but still need help with a couple of things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just got the solution back, and I did a real butchering on the code. But, I will post this so no one will have to suffer like I did:

```
# main function
    def main():
        # Local variables only have to define floats
        average = 0.0
        score1 = 0.0
        score2 = 0.0
        score3 = 0.0
        score4 = 0.0
        score5 = 0.0

        # Get scores
        score1 = float(input('Enter score 1:'))
        name1  = input('Enter name 1:')
        score2 = float(input('Enter score 2:'))
        name2  = input('Enter name 2:')
        score3 = float(input('Enter score 3:'))
        name3  = input('Enter name 3:')
        score4 = float(input('Enter score 4:'))
        name4  = input('Enter name  4:')
        score5 = float(input('Enter score 5:'))
        name5  = input('Enter name 5:')

        # Calculate average grade
        average = calculate_average(score1, score2, score3, score4, score5)

        #Display grade and average information in tabular form
        print('Name\t\tnumeric grade\tletter grade')
        print('----------------------------------------------------')
        print(name1 + ':\t\t', score1, '\t\t', determine_grade(score1))
        print(name2 + ':\t\t', score2, '\t\t', determine_grade(score2))
        print(name3 + ':\t\t', score3, '\t\t', determine_grade(score3))
        print(name4 + ':\t\t', score4, '\t\t', determine_grade(score4))
        print(name5 + ':\t\t', score5, '\t\t', determine_grade(score5))
        print('----------------------------------------------------')
        print ('Average score:\t', average, '\t\t', \
               determine_grade(average))

    # The calc_average function returns average of 5 grades 
    def calculate_average(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5):
        return  (s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5) / 5.0

    # The determine_grade function receives a numeric  
    # grade and returns the corresponding letter grade 
    def determine_grade(score):
        if score >= 90:
            return 'A'
        elif score >= 80:
            return 'B'
        elif score >= 70:
            return 'C'
        elif score >= 60:
            return 'D'
        else:
            return 'F'

    # Call the main function.
    main()
```