# Temperature conversion Table

Tags: python, temperature

I need to write a program that displays Celsius to Fahrenheit temperature conversion in a table.

**Question** -  What is the correct way to print a specific index within a list. [My attempt comes from the answer to a similar exercise outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458074/how-to-create-a-table-in-python). Thanks in advance.

This is my code

```
temp = range(0 , 101, 10)
tbl = []
tbl2 = []
for i in temp:
    cel = i
    tbl.append(cel)
    fah = (i * 9/5) + 32
    tbl2.append(fah)
    print(cel, fah)

print('Celsius\t\tFahrenheit')
print('-------------------')
print(tbl(0) + ':\t\t', tbl2(0))
print('-------------------')
```

This is my output
[image]

Comment: `print(str(tbl[0]) + ':\t\t', tbl2[0])`

Answer (score 2):

Functions are called with parenthesis(). Indexes are accessed with with brackets[0]:

```py
print(tbl[0] + ':\t\t', tbl2[0])
```